# PHP - Using a method similar to forking to define one constant multiple times? (Windows)

Tags: php, exec, constants, fork

I'm currently working with an existing application that defines a couple constants on the login of a user. For example, if Alice logs in `SOME_CONSTANT` is defined as `1`, while if Bob logs in `SOME_CONSTANT` is defined as `2`. Now I'm trying to write a script that will do a couple of things as if it were Alice and a couple things as if it were Bob. By "as if it were" I mean that `SOME_CONSTANT` is defined one way for one iteration and another way for the next iteration. Unfortunately, constants are not the best at switching values and refactoring the application to change these from being constants is not an option at this time.

One method I had considered was to use pcntl_fork(). I would fork before the time the constants were defined and run a separate process for each constant. However, I would like this script to be able to run on Windows as well as Linux. At the moment the pcntl extension is not directly supported for Windows. And I'm going to try to avoid getting everything working through Cygwin if I can help it.

Another method I had considered was having the script call children scripts using `exec("php childscript.php constant_value")`. Will this method allow one child script to define a constant one way and another child script define it another way? I think it should, but I haven't tested it yet. Also, is there any other major problems anyone can see with this method?

Is there another method I haven't considered that would be a better choice? Thank you for your time.

Comment: So... you want a constant that's variable, but need to pretend it's still a constant? bite the bullet and change to using a variable.

Comment: I hope to eventually change these to being variables. These were constants before I started working on the project. However, this is a huge change that I won't have time to work on at the moment. I know it's the "correct" way to go about things, but it's not a reasonable choice for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method of using `exec()` to call the PHP child script appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noticed, using a `const` variable is not a viable method to handle your task. Additionally, even if you didn't need to write a script to do something with multiple users, a single instance of this wouldn't work - you would need to "set the constant" when the user logs in, which you can't do.

If you're looking for a pseudo-`readonly` implementation, and you are using OOP-style, you can add a `private` variable and override the [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) magic-method. So, whenenver the outside requests `SOME_CONSTANT`, your class will return the value of `_someFakeConstant`. Then, in your `login()` or `switchUser()` method inside the class you can safely change the value.

Example:

```
class User {
    private $_someFakeConstant = -1;

    public function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'SOME_CONSTANT') {
            return $this->_someFakeConstant;
        }
        // handle undefined variables; trigger_error() will work (see example on php.net)
    }

    public function login() {
        // logic to "identify" the user
        $this->_someFakeConstant = 1;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->login();
echo $user->SOME_CONSTANT;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, unless I'm reading what you're saying wrong, this still requires me to swap out all existing constants with something new. The system I'm working on was based around these constants long before I started working on the project. I hope to eventually switch out the constants for something better, but for this script it's not worth the refactor. I can use other work-arounds if there's no good way of doing this. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @golmschenk I'm not sure I get what you're saying. Your question asks about how to have a different (constant) value for each user, but you don't want a different value for each user? I'm more than glad to try to help, but I think we're on different pages =P

Comment: No no, you're right about what I'm looking for. I'm just saying the method to go about achieving what I'm looking for isn't practical for me. The application I'm working on has been based around these constants since before I started working on the project. And to the swap out the way these constants are defined is likely going to be more work then I'll have time for at the moment. I do want do change their values, but I don't think I'll be able to reasonable change what the constants are right now (i.e. changing them from being constants to a constant-like value). Does that make sense?